# Toggling table columns with dynamically added rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am toggling columns in a table using a data-col attribute. It works when the table is already there.

However, I have a javascript function that adds new rows to the table. How can I also automatically set column visibility of dynamically added rows based on checkbox status?

**HTML**

```
<div id="tablemodal">
    <h4>Select Columns to Hide or Show</h4>
    <input checked="checked" data-col='column1' type="checkbox" /> Route 
    <input checked="checked" data-col='column2' type="checkbox" /> Distance</div>
  <input checked="checked" data-col='column3' type="checkbox" /> speed</div>
  <div>
    <table id="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="col" data-col="column1">route</th>
          <th class="col" data-col="column2">distance</th>
          <th class="col" data-col="column3">speed</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col" data-col="column1">washington to new york</td>
          <td class="col" data-col="column2">1000 miles</td>
          <td class="col" data-col="column3">300 mph</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="add new row" id="button">
  </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
  $(function() {
    $("input[data-col]").on("change", function() {
      var col = $(this).data("col");
      $(".col[data-col='" + col + "']").toggle();
    });
  })

  $( "#button" ).click(function() {
    $('#table').append('<tr>'+
                       '<td class="col" data-col="column1">NY to Philly</td>'+
                       '<td class="col" data-col="column2">300 miles</td>'+
                       '<td class="col" data-col="column3">200mph</td>')
  });
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/com7ef5u/12/

Comment: thanks Tony, I have changed my code to  $('body').on('change', 'input[data-col]', function() {
var col = $(this).data("col");
      $(".col[data-col='" + col + "']").toggle();
});   but this event only triggers on change, when the rows are added nothing changes, so how can I implement it to check if it is toggled or not?

Comment: @Bruno you can manually fire the event when adding the rows by doing `$('body').change()`.

Comment: @JohnnyKutnowski I am not sure I understand.

Comment: you were saying the event only triggers when the `body` element changes, but you can also trigger it manually by selecting an element (`body` in this case) and adding `.change()` with no parameters after it.
Straight from the jQuery API: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Javascript like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/com7ef5u/15/):

This code will check the inputs and toggle them if necessary.

```
$(function() {
  $("input[data-col]").on("change", function() {
    var col = $(this).data("col");
    $(".col[data-col='" + col + "']").toggle();
  });
})
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
  $('#table').append('<tr id="addedrow">'+
    '<td class="col" data-col="column1">NY to Philly</td>'+
    '<td class="col" data-col="column2">300 miles</td>'+
    '<td class="col" data-col="column3">200mph</td>');
  $("input[data-col]").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      var col = $(this).data("col");
      $("#addedrow .col[data-col='" + col + "']").toggle();
    }
  });   
  $("#addedrow").removeAttr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
     var newRow = $($('#table').children().children()[1]).clone();
     //set values
     $('#table').append(newRow);
});
```